# How to post a button's value in html form (PHP)

Tags: php

i have javascript that changes an input's value and when i post the form, the field is not transferred

```
<input id="exampleID" type="button" name="exampleButton" value="click me" onclick="changeValue()">
```

when the button is clicked the value (displayed to the user) changes to "Clicked"
then when i post the form it the value is left behind

```
if(isset($_POST['exampleButton'])) {
    echo "true";
}
```

this doesn't echo anything
what should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `input button` control won't send any value to the server on submit, as it is made to interact with javascript. If you need to send a dynamic value, store it in a field (like an `input hidden` control), or, if you insist to send it through a button, change its type to `submit`

Answer (score 1):

You can change value of hidden field:

```html
<input id="exampleID" type="hidden" name="exampleButton" value="">
<input type="button" value="click me" onclick="changeValue()">
<script>
function changeValue(){
document.getElementById('exampleID').value = "Clicked";
}
</script>
```